# I am unable to manipulate the data returned with yfinance

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance, yfinance

This might be a silly question what I am doing here, but I am unfamiliar with this. I am playing around with the `yfinance` library to build a small script to track certain tickers. The thing is, let's see for example that I want to see what is the value of S&P500 for today and yesterday so later I can compare, this is as far as I got using the tutorial:

```
import yfinance as yf

SP500 = yf.Ticker('^GSPC')
SP500 = SP500.history(period="2d")

print(SP500['Close'])
```

So what I am looking for is the price of that particular ticker at close. But when I run this code, what I get is:

```
Date
2020-03-20    2304.92
2020-03-23    2237.40
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

I am unfamiliar with data offered this way. I am used to receive back tuples, lists, something I can work on. I have tried extracting the numbers only from the lines the pythonic way but I can't get any joy. In this case I am only interested in getting the `2304.92` and `2237.40` numbers to further work on them.

Does anyone have any idea how can I extract these numbers off this matrix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like its a pandas DataFrame. add `.values` to your print.

Comment: Thank you very much @yoav_aaa, that was exactly it. I wasn't aware it was being managed with pandas. I'm not familiar with pandas, that's the reason. Thanks agin, that solved it

Comment: The [docs](https://aroussi.com/post/python-yahoo-finance) clearly explain that it's backwards compatible with `pandas-datareader`.